# Integrating mailkick and ahoy_email in Rails app causes SystemStackError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that we're adding mailing list functionality too.  I'm trying to integrate two gems, ahoy_email (0.3.0) and mailkick (0.1.4), and running into a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` error.

The mailer code is simple:

```
class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
  # ...
  def generated_recommendations(recommendations)                                               
    @recommendations = recommendations
        mail(subject: "Recommendations generated for #{Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}")      
  end 
end
```

Before it crashes, the stack trace looks like this:

```
--> #0  Mailkick::Mailer.mail(headers#Hash, &block#NilClass) at /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mailkick-0.1.4/lib/mailkick/mailer.rb:4
#1  AhoyEmail::Mailer.mail_with_ahoy(headers#Hash, &block#NilClass) at /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ahoy_email-0.3.0/lib/ahoy_email/mailer.rb:27
#2  Mailkick::Mailer.mail(headers#Hash, &block#NilClass) at /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mailkick-0.1.4/lib/mailkick/mailer.rb:4
#3  AhoyEmail::Mailer.mail_with_ahoy(headers#Hash, &block#NilClass) at /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ahoy_email-0.3.0/lib/ahoy_email/mailer.rb:27
#4  Mailkick::Mailer.mail(headers#Hash, &block#NilClass) at      /home/mike/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mailkick-0.1.4/lib/mailkick/mailer.rb:4
```

It looks like each gem calls the `mail` method in the other (or `mail_with_ahoy` in AhoyEmail due to an alias_method_chain call, see below).  I traced through it with byebug and the relevant Mailkick code is (see line with ***)

```
module Mailkick                                                                                
  module Mailer                                                                                
    def mail(headers = {}, &block)                                                             
      message = super  # *** This ends up calling AhoyEmail::Mailer.mail_with_ahoy

      Mailkick::Processor.new(message).process

      message
    end
  end
end
```

and the relevant AhoyEmail code is (see ***)

```
module AhoyEmail                                                                               
  module Mailer
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend ClassMethods                                                                 
      base.class_eval do
        # ...
        alias_method_chain :mail, :ahoy                                                        
      end                                                                                      
    end                                                                                        

    module ClassMethods                                                                        
    # ...
    def mail_with_ahoy(headers = {}, &block)
      # this mimics what original method does                                                  
      return message if @_mail_was_called && headers.blank? && !block

      message = mail_without_ahoy(headers, &block)  # *** This calls Mailkick::Mailer.mail
      AhoyEmail::Processor.new(message, self).process                                          
      message
    end     
  end     
end
```

The two gems add their functionality a little differently, in the case of AhoyEmail it is via:

```
ActionMailer::Base.send :include, AhoyEmail::Mailer
```

and in the case of Mailkick it is via:

```
ActionMailer::Base.send(:prepend, Mailkick::Mailer)
```

To me it looks like the gems just conflict (since they're both making changes to `ActionMailer::Base.mail` that don't play well together) and I don't see an obvious workaround.  I was surprised since Mailkick is referenced in the Readme for Ahoy Email, so I was thinking I may be missing something obvious.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the version of the `ahoy_email` gem I was using (from RubyGems) had since been updated on github to resolve this issue.  The solution was to updated the corresponding line in the Gemfile to:

`gem 'ahoy_email', github: 'ankane/ahoy_email'`

See the relevant issue on github here:
https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email/issues/61

The diff in the `ahoy_email` gem where this is resolved is here:
https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email/commit/9416ab989b942cd556d09380f9072c260c2d6551

The use of `alias_method_chain` is gone, replaced with Module#prepend, which fixes things.  Looking around a little I see that `alias_method_chain` will be deprecated in Rails 5 (see https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19434).

**Edit 2016-05-12:** A new version (0.3.1) of the gem was released with this fix, so now I've updated my Gemfile to:
`gem 'ahoy_email', '>= 0.3.1'`